# JLabel not changing colors on MouseEvent? java

Tags: java, swing, colors, mouseevent, mouselistener

Ive been adding on this program for a while now slowly developing it from a simple calculator, but now the the program has no errors but is not giving me the output i want. it should change colors to Blue but wont. i added resultPane.setForeground(Color.BLUE); but wont update the JLabel

```
public class TestCalculator {
private ResultPane resultPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestCalculator();
}

public TestCalculator() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                resultPane = new ResultPane();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setGlassPane(resultPane);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            frame.add(new CalculatorPane(resultPane));
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

public class ResultPane extends JPanel {

    private JLabel result;
    private Timer timer;

    private int xDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;
    private int yDelta = (Math.random() > 0.5) ? 1 : -1;



    public ResultPane() {
        setOpaque(false);
        setLayout(null);
        result = new JLabel();
        Font font = result.getFont();
        font = font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 26f);
        result.setFont(font);
        add(result);
        HandlerClass handler = new HandlerClass();
        result.addMouseListener(handler);
        result.addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Point point = result.getLocation();
                point.x += xDelta;
                point.y += yDelta;
                if (point.x < 0) {
                    point.x = 0;
                    xDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.x + result.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                    point.x = getWidth() - result.getWidth();
                    xDelta *= -1;
                }
                if (point.y < 0) {
                    point.y = 0;
                    yDelta *= -1;
                } else if (point.y + result.getHeight() > getHeight()) {
                    point.y = getHeight() - result.getHeight();
                    yDelta *= -1;
                }
                result.setLocation(point);
                repaint();
            }

        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void setResult(Number number) {
        result.setText(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(number));
        result.setSize(result.getPreferredSize());
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public String getResultText() {
        return result.getText();
    }

}

public class CalculatorPane extends JPanel {

    private final ResultPane resultPane;

    private final JLabel firstNumberLabel = new JLabel("First Number:");
    private final JLabel secondNumberLabel = new JLabel("Second Number:");

    private final JTextField firstNumberField = new JTextField(5);
    private final JTextField secondNumberField = new JTextField(5);

    public double result = 0.0;

    public CalculatorPane(ResultPane resultPane) {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        this.resultPane = resultPane;

        JPanel fields = new JPanel();
        fields.add(firstNumberLabel);
        fields.add(firstNumberField);
        fields.add(secondNumberLabel);
        fields.add(secondNumberField);

        add(fields, gbc);

        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(new JButton(new AddAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new SubtractAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new MultiplyAction()));
        buttons.add(new JButton(new DivideAction()));

        add(buttons, gbc);

    }

    public class AddAction extends AbstractAction {

        public AddAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "+");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 + num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
                String resultText = resultPane.getResultText();
            firstNumberField.setText(resultText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class SubtractAction extends AbstractAction {

        public SubtractAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "-");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 - num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
                String resultText = resultPane.getResultText();
            firstNumberField.setText(resultText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class MultiplyAction extends AbstractAction {

        public MultiplyAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "x");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 * num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
                String resultText = resultPane.getResultText();
            firstNumberField.setText(resultText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }

    }
    public class DivideAction extends AbstractAction {

        public DivideAction() {
            putValue(NAME, "/");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double num1 = Double.parseDouble(firstNumberField.getText());
                double num2 = Double.parseDouble(secondNumberField.getText());

                double result = num1 / num2;
                resultPane.setResult(result);
                String resultText = resultPane.getResultText();
                firstNumberField.setText(resultText);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
            }
        }
    }

}
private class HandlerClass implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        resultPane.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        }
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
        }
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event){
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I'll give you credit for figuring out the how to use the `MouseListener`, nice work ;)  Take a look at the `MouseAdapter` class, it's an `abstract` implementation of the various mouse listeners with empty implementations of the methods.  It makes it cleaner to implement mouse handlers, you don't need to provide your own empty mouse event handler methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `MouseListener` you are setting the `JPanel`'s foreground color, not the `JLabel`'s:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    resultPane.setForeground(Color.BLUE); // This is the problem
}
```

`resultPane` is your custom JPanel.  You need to change it set the foreground color of the JLabel contained in this custom panel.  I would just add a method to `ResultPane` like such:

```
public void setLabelForeground(Color color) {
    result.setForeground(color);
}
```

Then call `resultPane.setLabelForeground(Color.BLUE);` in the `MouseListener`.

Also, not sure if this is what you were trying to do, but this will still only change the foreground color when you click on the JLabel...?

Comment: Yeah i want the foreground color to change when you click the moving label

Comment: i get 2 errors, one on line resultPane.setLabelForeground(Color.BLUE); and one on line result.setForeground(color);

Comment: my bad wasent adding to methood to ResultPane. Thanks for the fix